# Short word that means "someone who takes notes"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I have *stenographer*, *secretary* and *recorder* already (but they don't seem to be precise enough) and I'm hoping to find a shorter word if possible please.

Some context, I'm a software engineer and the naming of entities within a program needs some precision. Since I was coding a simple example for a more non technical user I wanted a shorted and more precise word.

Comment: lol - doesn't matter but 4-5 chars is about the size I'm thinking about

Comment: I'd prefer to see more context. Why aren't the words you mentioned good enough? Where do you intend to use it? Why is it important to you that the word be short?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Scribe](http://thesaurus.com/browse/scribe) is one of the shortest words for "one who transcribes professionally".

It's difficult to be precise and short sometimes: a [clerk](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/clerk) might take notes, but probably doesn't do this as a sole task.

Some longer but more precise alternatives are [notetaker](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/notetaker) or [transcriptionist](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/transcriptionist).

Comment: Note that like *clerk*, the more usual meaning for *scribe* is more general than just note-taking. It means basically someone who writes, be that notes at a meeting or books in a monastery.

Comment: "Scribe" is the preferred word in the some of the companies I have worked for (and with). None of us were professional scribes, but we performed that role (we took turns) [in meetings and reviews](http://getitdone.quickanddirtytips.com/How-to-Run-a-Meeting.aspx). We were all engineers.

Answer (score 6):

You could try [amanuensis](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/amanuensis):

> a person employed to write what another dictates or to copy what has
>   been written by another; secretary.

[Dictionary.com]

Answer (score 2):

How about "[rapporteur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapporteur)?" An old French word for someone who reports. It's a term used at the United Nations and other international organizations.

> a person who is appointed by an organization to report on the
>   proceedings of its meetings.

[Wikipedia]